# How to make the opacity layer same size as img

Tags: css, opacity, layer

How to make the opacity layer the same size as the img.
Right now the opacity layer has the same size as my img, but that's only because I edited it too the same size, but when I make my screen smaller it won't be the same size anymore as the img.

PS: is there a way to make content: "Work"; show up in the middle of the img instead at the top?

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nSLXF/

Html:

```
<body>

<img id="logo" src="Images/logo.png" alt="Logo">
<hr id="line"  size="4" color="#09b981" align="center">

<a id="reach" href="about.html"><img src="Images/Reach.png" alt="Reach"></a>
<a id="contact" href="contact.html"><img src="Images/contact.png" alt="contact"></a>
<a id="werk" href="work.html"> <img src="Images/work.png" alt="werk"> </a>



</body>
```

css:

```
 #reach img
        {
            text-align: center;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            height:auto;
        }
    #reach:after {
            content:'Work';
            color:#fff;
            position:absolute;
            margin-top:11.2%;
            margin-left: 25.2%;
            width:49.6%; height:40.3%;
            top:0; left:0;
            background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
            opacity:0;
            transition: all 0.8s;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
            font-size: 42px;
            font-family: Helvetica;
        }

        #reach:hover:after 
        {
            opacity:1;
        }
```

Comment: Post you html please.

Comment: And prepare a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/)!

Comment: hi thanks for reply, I updated it with html and fiddle, but I don't know how to add images so it looks kinda weird right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact you set the `size` and `left`, `top` wrongly for the layer which is actually a `:after` element. You can just set `left:0`, `top:0` and `width:100%`, `height:100%` for it and use `position:relative` for the `a` element. The size of `img` should fit the size of the parent `a` element:

```
#reach  {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  position:relative; /* add this */
}
#reach:after {
  content:'Work';
  color:#fff;
  position:absolute;        
  /* update this */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  /*------*/
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0;
  transition: all 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.8s;
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/nSLXF/1/)

Comment: Thanks man and sorry for a other question but do you know how to make content show up in the middle of the img?

Comment: @user3406286 it's a fairly complicated thing in your case (in which you use pseudo-element to render the text). I think we have to use `:after` element to render the background while the `:before` element to render the text, that way we can center the text using transform. Here is the updated demo http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/nSLXF/2/

Comment: Thank you! you honor your name, king!